# Efficient querying of Django queryset intersection with different models

Tags: django

I'm trying to do a slightly more complicated Django queryset interaction and I've run into a hurdle.

```
class A(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    x = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    y = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class B(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    x = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    y = models.CharField(max_length=10)

a_queryset = user.a_set.filter(x__in=("foo", "bar", "baz"))
b_queryset = B.objects.filter(???)
```

Anyone happen to know of an efficient way to generate a queryset of B objects that have the same x/y pairs as a given A queryset? Is there a quick way of doing this given an arbitrary a_queryset?

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it using queryset because, `A` and `B` even when they have an indirect relationship(`user` model) you are not querying using it, so there is not relationship between them.

You can do it using python built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

Given the `a_queryset` you can get the `(x, y)` pairs and build a query using [`Q objects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

First, get the `(x, y)` unique pairs from `a_queryset`:

```
xy_pairs = a_queryset.values_list('x', 'y').distinct()
# [('x1', 'y1'), ('x2', 'y2'), ('x1', 'y2'), ('x2', 'y1')]
```

For a pair `('x1', 'y1')` you can easily search for all the `B` objects as following:

```
b_objs = B.objects.filter(x='x1', y='y1')
```

But, here you need to build a query which looks something like this:

```
# (x='x1' AND y='y1') OR (x='x2' AND y='y2') .... etc.
```

and you can achieve this by creating `Q objects`

```
# first create AND queries for different (x, y) pairs
q_and_queries = [(Q(x=x) & Q(y=y)) for x, y in xy_pairs]

#[<Q: (AND: ('x', 'x1'), ('y', 'y1'))>,
# <Q: (AND: ('x', 'x2'), ('y', 'y2'))>,
# <Q: (AND: ('x', 'x1'), ('y', 'y2'))>,
# <Q: (AND: ('x', 'x2'), ('y', 'y1'))>]

# then combine those queries using OR
q_or_query = Q()
for q in q_and_queries:
    q_or_query |= q

# <Q: (OR: (AND: ), (AND: ('x', 'x1'), ('y', 'y1')), (AND: ('x', 'x2'), ('y', 'y2')), (AND: ('x', 'x1'), ('y', 'y2')), (AND: ('x', 'x2'), ('y', 'y1')))>
```

Now, you can use the final query `q_or_query` to get the desired queryset from model `B`:

```
b_queryset = B.objects.filter(q_or_query)
```